# Resolving jquery conflicts?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery vendor script(jQuery file upload) I am using, but this script is not working as '$' is conflicting with another script.

I've tried using [jQuery.noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) with no luck.

Other approach will be to change all the vendor "$" to "jQuery" on all occurences, but I'm not really interested in modifying vendor sources.

Is there any other way to do this?

Thanks for any input!

Comment: Could you show us how you've tried using `jQuery.noConflict()`?

Answer (score 0):

Include the other library first, then include jQuery. After that, before executing any statement, execute `$.noConflict()` first to revert `$` back to its original object.

This should work and it's not necessary to modify the jQuery source code.